# Keycloak is stripping the port from my redirect_uri in the Location header. Why?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have the following allowed redirect uri set for my client: `exp://192.168.2.212:19000`

After a code exchange using the following URL:

```
GET /auth/realms/xxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth?code_challenge=m71Cl...D4hw&redirect_uri=exp%3A%2F%2F192.168.2.212%3A19000&client_id=3B03...

X-Forwarded-For: 178.84.x.x
X-Forwarded-Host: oidc.production.my.domain.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Server: 09918a799a23
X-Real-Ip: 178.84.x.x
```

I get a `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` with the following Location field:

```
Location: exp://192.168.2.212?state=T0pvzPyHF6&session_state=b1cf16ad-b.....
```

**The port is missing**. My (Expo) client in android emulator then barfs about not being able to connect to `192.168.2.212 port 80`. Naturally.

I am using the docker hub images 11.0.0

How can I prevent this? Is it a bug?

(The iOS version of my app uses a different `redirect_uri` (`exp://127.0.0.1:19000`), but although Keycloak strips the port there as well and it receives a `Location: exp://127.0.0.1?state=T0p...` it *does* connect to port 19000 and works fine for some reason.)

EDIT: Note that authentication works fine on iOS, and I run exactly the same Keycloak settings in iOS as Android (It's a React Native application).

Keycloak logs no error, and the following debug message:

```
13:24:33,365 DEBUG [org.keycloak.events] (default task-47) type=LOGIN, realmId=neemop, clientId=3B03FD35, userId=28619cd3-c51d-4756-9d06-fb47********, ipAddress=178.84.x.x, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=exp://192.168.2.212:19000, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=a0faa4d4-6826-4c2f-9243-*******, response_mode=query, username=ron.arts@mydomain.com, authSessionParentId=a0faa4d4-6826-4c2f-9243-*******, authSessionTabId=-Pn******
```

shows the redirect_uri is parsed correctly. It's just that in the actual HTTP response the Location: header omits the port. Which imho should not happen.

Comment: What is the configuration of the keycloak adapter? The allowed redirect uri(s) is not responsible of the actual redirect. Please provide the whole configuration and docker image config.

Comment: I'm not using the Keycloak adapter, but Expo AuthSession. Note that authentication works fine, and keycloak does not log an error at all. Added extra info above.

Comment: OK I see. Anything I say won't help then :)

Comment: Out of interested, have you got keycloak successfully working with Expo? I am attempting to do this but unable to without any documentation.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. The KeyCloak docs do contain everything you need, but security is hard to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another bug has been submitted to keycloak team:

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-17141

a fix is available in keycloak version >= 13.0.0

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to answer this question!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-9405?_sscc=t

Tested on 12.0.4 and it still occurs. It appears to be an issue with any non-http(s) protocol